# best way to apply salesforce styles on custom component

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm using a custom javascript grid (jqxgrid) on a visualforce page.

What is the best way to get and apply the salesforces native css classes?

There exists some style cheatsheet ? I was searching on the official doc unsuccessfuly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesnt sound like something that has a "quick fix".

You would need your custom components to output markup that matched the Salesforce standards or write your own custom CSS to map our markup to the styles.

If possible I'd suggest the former.

Comment: It seems to be harder than I supposed. Thx